# MySQL - Join with latest value from another table with a dynamic table name

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with the following tables:

```
Items (ItemId, ItemName)
Item1 (Time, Value)
Item2 (Time, Value)
Item3 (Time, Value)
Item4 (Time, Value)
.
.
ItemX (Time, Value)
subscriptions (sub_id, sub_topic, pin, item_id, device_id)
```

The `item_id` in `subscriptions` table is foreign key to `ItemId` in `Items` table.

The numbered Item tables have state information on when the item was turned ON or OFF. All the Item tables are generated and I run the risk of breaking something if I modify them.

I want to be able to get all rows of a specific `device_id` from `subscriptions` and join it with the last recorded state from the corresponding Item table, like so:

```
+--------+-----------+-----+---------+-----------+-------+
| sub_id | sub_topic | pin | item_id | device_id | value |
+--------+-----------+-----+---------+-----------+-------+
|      1 | topic1    |   5 |       1 |         1 | OFF   | <-- Last recorded Value from Item1
|      2 | topic2    |   4 |       4 |         1 | OFF   | <-- Last recorded Value from Item4
|      3 | topic3    |  14 |       3 |         1 | ON    | <-- Last recorded Value from Item3
|      4 | topic4    |  12 |       2 |         1 | ON    | <-- Last recorded Value from Item2
+--------+-----------+-----+---------+-----------+-------+
```

I am using the following queries to get all rows of a specific device_id and then manually get the last recorded state for each row:

```
SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE device_id=1;
SELECT Value FROM Item1 WHERE Time=(SELECT MAX(Time) FROM Item1);
```

But I do not know how to combine the two to get what I want. The name of the table to check the state has to be determined dynamically based on the item_id of each row from the first query.

I have created the tables in SQLFiddle to make it easier for someone to help me with this.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/392fe